# One eigenvalue and eigensystem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n,n}$ has one engenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ and its engensystem $V_{\lambda}$ has dimension that equals to $n$. How to show that $A = \lambda I_{n}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by eigensystem, but it seems that you are saying you can diagonalize $A$. If that's the case diagonalize it and you'll get your result almost instantly.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the dimension of the eigenspace is $n$. From here $A$ diagonalizble and the result follows.

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Any vector is an eigenvector of $\lambda$...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $A$ with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors associated to it. This means that $A$ is diagonalizable. Hence there exists an invertible matrix $B$ such that
$$A=B^{-1}DB$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with $\lambda$ as each diagonal element. Then we can write
$$A=B^{-1}DB=B^{-1}(\lambda I)B=\lambda B^{-1}IB=\lambda B^{-1}BI=\lambda I$$